# Python textract reads split-page PDFs in the wrong order

Tags: python, pdf

I am using Python's textract library to read PDF files and extract specific info from them. So far it works perfectly on 99% of the files. Error happens when it reads split-page style PDF.

[image: Like this one.]

It messes up the order and treat the first 2 pages shown as one page, so it goes to read line from the most left to the most right. It is very critical for me to deal with split pages as individual pages when I read the left first then the right for the whole PDF.

[image: Example of how textract read the above file.]

Here's my code:

```
text = textract.process("pdfs2/filename.pdf")
text = text.decode('utf-8')
```

I don't know if other libraries doesn't have the same issue, but I tried PyPDF2, pdfminer, pdf2text, and so far textract is the one with the lowest error issue in even reading the text from the PDF. So I need to find a solution with textract.

Comment: If you haven't done so, I suggest you to try [PDF Plumber](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber), very powerful, well documented, and easy to use python library for work with PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the [Textract Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/automatically-extract-text-and-structured-data-from-documents-with-amazon-textract/) in particular the section "Multi-column detection and reading order". They give you an example of how to process the response and effectively 'sort' the data into columns or in your case pages.

Comment: AWS Textract is a different library, unrelated to the one OP is asking about, [Python Textract](https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).